# Angular 8 Plotly - chart as class getter freezes page

Tags: angular, plotly, getter, plotly.js

I am using `plotly.js-(basic-dist-min) v1.52.2` and `angular-plotly.js v1.5.0` inside an Angular 8 Project. Everything is working fine, with the only exception that if I return the "graph object", so the data array and layout from a getter, the webpage freezes. I suppose this is because plotly is calling the getter to often, though I cannot check because the devtools are also frozen. The getter is as simple as:

```
public get chart(): { data: any, layout: any } | null {
    const data = computeSomeChartData(); // just one array filter

    return { data: [...], layout: {...} }
    // return null if no data
}
```

and the template looks like:

```
<plotly-plot
    [data]="chart.data"
    [layout]="chart.layout"
    [config]="{ displayModeBar: false }"
    [useResizeHandler]="true"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    *ngIf="chart !== null"
></plotly-plot>
```

How can I keep the chart as a getter, but prevent the page from freezing? (Preferably without a timeout or something like this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you have shared, looks like problem might be due to the way your getter is returning new object all the time. Try to store you chart data in some intemediatory variable and return it instead and it should fix your issue.

Just for reference, it could be something like:

```
private computedChart?: { data: any, layout: any };

public get chart(): { data: any, layout: any } | null {
    if (!this.computedChart) {
        const data = computeSomeChartData();
        this.computedChart = { data: [...], layout: {...}  };
    }

    return this.computedChart;
}
```